# nearest member aditional atribute analysis

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have following dataframe df(sample):

```
         lat        lon  crs   Band1              x             y
0  41.855584  20.619156  b''  1568.0  468388.198606  4.633812e+06
1  41.855584  20.622590  b''  1562.0  468673.173031  4.633811e+06
2  41.855584  20.626023  b''  1605.0  468958.147443  4.633810e+06
3  41.859017  20.612290  b''  1598.0  467819.970900  4.634196e+06
4  41.859017  20.615723  b''  1593.0  468104.930108  4.634195e+06
5  41.859017  20.619156  b''  1600.0  468389.889303  4.634193e+06
6  41.859017  20.622590  b''  1586.0  468674.848486  4.634192e+06
7  41.859017  20.626023  b''  1577.0  468959.807656  4.634191e+06
8  41.859017  20.629456  b''  1584.0  469244.766814  4.634190e+06
9  41.859017  20.632889  b''  1598.0  469529.725959  4.634188e+06
```

fields `x` and `y` are coordinates in xy plane, and `Band1` is point elevation ( in essence it is z coordinate ). Dataframe is rectangle grid with `x` and `y`as center grid coordinate and `Band1` as grid elevation.

How can I detect which of grid cells is highest in `Band1` against neighboring cells?

Expected output in this case is additional column in dataframe with boolean value defining that cell is highest in elevation `Band1` prior to neighboring 4 cells.

I can easily get neigbouring grid distances and indices with:

```
X=df[['x','y']].to_numpy()
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=5, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(X)
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(X)
```

With Indices output:

```
array([[0, 1, 5, 6, 4],
       [1, 2, 0, 6, 7],
       [2, 1, 7, 8, 6],
       [3, 4, 5, 0, 6],
       [4, 5, 3, 0, 6],
       [5, 6, 4, 0, 1],
       [6, 7, 5, 1, 2],
       [7, 8, 6, 2, 1],
       [8, 9, 7, 2, 6],
       [9, 8, 7, 2, 6]], dtype=int64)
```

I can loop though dataframe and compare all members, but its resource consuming since i have 1M rows.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `indices` to get the corresponding value in the column `Band1`, then use [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) with the parameter axis set to 1 to get the position of the highest value per row. If the value is 0, then it means that the Band1 of this row is higher than the ones of the neighbors like:

```
df['local_high'] = np.argmax(df['Band1'].to_numpy()[indices], axis=1)==0
```

and you get

```
         lat        lon  crs   Band1              x          y  local_high
0  41.855584  20.619156  b''  1568.0  468388.198606  4633812.0       False
1  41.855584  20.622590  b''  1562.0  468673.173031  4633811.0       False
2  41.855584  20.626023  b''  1605.0  468958.147443  4633810.0        True
3  41.859017  20.612290  b''  1598.0  467819.970900  4634196.0       False
4  41.859017  20.615723  b''  1593.0  468104.930108  4634195.0       False
5  41.859017  20.619156  b''  1600.0  468389.889303  4634193.0        True
6  41.859017  20.622590  b''  1586.0  468674.848486  4634192.0       False
7  41.859017  20.626023  b''  1577.0  468959.807656  4634191.0       False
8  41.859017  20.629456  b''  1584.0  469244.766814  4634190.0       False
9  41.859017  20.632889  b''  1598.0  469529.725959  4634188.0       False
```